# Magento 404 page not found when trying to navigate to product url

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, url, products

When I got a product and it's simple without a parent and I call ->getProductUrl() I get a url like this:

> $_product->getProductUrl();

And this is giving me:

http://testdata.com/slim-fit-dobby-oxford-shirt.html

Meanwhile, a simple product with parent is returning a URL like this, which works:

http://testdata.com/french-cuff-cotton-twill-oxford-570.html

And If I try to access that url, I will get 404 page not found. Any help with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of getProductUrl() I created the whole link by:  + getProductPath(). This way the linked worked, also do not forget to change the option so that the product is visible, from "Not visible individually"